# How to remove nan values and merge lower rows with upper rows in a live dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, api, group-by, nan

I'm trying to automate a trade strategy. I'm using Angelbroking stock market API to create live dataframe.

The API I'm using fetches only open high low close values excluding date. So I mixed a python time program with API to get both current datetime and OHLC values. Below is the code I'm working on-

```
while (True):
#below code fetches current date and time 
IST = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
datetime_ist = datetime.now(IST)
Datetime=datetime_ist.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

#API to fetch last traded price(LTP)of a stock
exchange = "NSE"
tradingsymbol = "SBIN-EQ"
symboltoken = 3045
a=SmartApi.ltpData("NSE", "SBIN-EQ", "3045")

#creating datetime and LTP DataFrames
df = pd.DataFrame([a['data']])
df1= pd.DataFrame([Datetime])
df1.columns = ['Datetime']

#joining both DataFrames
df2 = pd.concat([df1, df])
```

After joining both DataFrames df and df1 I'm getting Nan values in both rows like in the below image-

[After joining DataFrames.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kYRT.jpg)

So, I tried grouping the data to remove Nan values.

```
#Grouping the data
df3=df2.groupby('Datetime').max().reset_index()
display(df3)
```

Now, grouping datetime only outputs datetime and shows Nan values in OHLC columns and when I group OHLC columns I'm getting Nan in datetime column like below

[Datetime grouping.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIJfk.jpg)

Being a beginner in python I'm unable to understand what am I missing or doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to attach the datetime column of the same length to the OHLC dataframe. `axis=0` is for rows while `axis=1` is for columns. By default, pandas uses `axis=0`, so you need to specify your preferred change to `axis=1`.

**Try changing your concat to this:**

```
df2 = pd.concat([df1, df], axis=1)
```

In a scenario where you get `InvalidIndexError`:

```
pd.concat([df1.reset_index(), df], axis=1)
```

An alternative would be to simply use `join()`:

```
df.join(df1)
```

**Word of advice:** It's good practice to reset the index before using `join()` or `concat()` if you are trying to produce a dataframe from 2 different dataframes.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have tried the methods you've mentioned and it worked. One last question. I'm getting duplicate column names like Datetime column and date under it and again Datetime column and date under it and so on. Please refer to the images I have attached in the description. Thanks again.